# Amazon Web Services - Why IAM does not support ARN for AutoScaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am just wondering why IAM policies do not support AutoScaling ARNs in the "Resource" field ?

(the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingWithAutoScaling.html#AutoScaling_ARN_Format%20documentation) explicitly says that ARNs are not supported)

Comment: Can you explain your use-case or need for this functionality? There might be an alternative method.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can't comment on behalf of the OP, but we share the same AWS account between multiple projects. The aim would be to restrict permissions so that user X can only manipulate resources bound to project Z. That needs specifying targets in IAM policy. AutoScalingGroups are one of the resources (among many others). With ASGs, luckily, we can use tags, so I personally don't need ARN. Of course, if tags are not set, then ARN would be useful.

Comment: By my last comment, I mean AWS supports tags on `AutoScalingGroup` but unfortunately not on `LaunchConfiguration`, `ScalingPolicy`, etc. so tags are not really a solution :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An **ARN** (Amazon Resource Name) is used to refer to a specific resource in AWS.

Selective IAM policies do include the ability to [specify resource-specific permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html), but an Auto Scaling group is not included.

**IAM policies** can grant permission to use specific API calls (eg `autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity`), but these permissions are granted for **all** auto scaling groups. It is not possible to only grant such permissions for one auto scaling group.

However, Amazon EC2 permissions can be granted to specific resources and this can be done based on tags. Therefore, it should be possible to grant permissions to perform actions (eg reboot) on EC2 instances launched from a particular auto scaling group since the name of the auto scaling group is stored as a tag.

Answer (score 3):

From May 15 2017, AWS Autoscaling started supporting resource level permissions.

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/introducing-auto-scaling-resource-level-permissions/
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/control-access-using-iam.html

Comment: Unfortunately (as of writing comment), you can't simulate this in the IAM Policy Simulator